# Can I work In Germany as a non-EU citizen if I am married to a EU-citizen?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, work-permit

Mi wife is a EU citizen (not Germany). I am not. We are currently living outside the EU. I have non-temporary employment contract with a German company, but I haven't been able to go there, since the German embassy has taken months to answer my request for a work permit.

As the spouse of a EU citizen, can I just go there with my regular passport and get a work permit? How long would that take? I know that in some parts of the EU it is like this, but I think Germany has tighter laws regarding this kind of immigration.

Comment: Would your wife be moving to Germany with you?

Comment: If your EU spouse accompanies you when moving to Germany, then yes. After registration of your residence, you are eligible for a **residence card** which will allow you to work.

Comment: @Relaxed yes, she will be.

Comment: @MarkJohnson who are "those citizens" that may apply for a residence permit? Are you saying I can apply either to a residence permit and a work permit OR to a residence card? Which you'll say is faster?

Comment: @Federico (The original comment was deleted) [Only nationals of Australia, Canada, Israel, Japan, New Zealand, South Korea and the United States may apply for the necessary residence title after arrival in Germany.](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/newsroom/buergerservice/faq/07-arbeitsvisum/606666)

Comment: @Federico Once you have registered as a family member on an EU Citizen, you can start to work immediately.

Comment: @Federico Then going the EU citizen's family route is definitely faster and easier. This is EU law, not something Germany could have tighter rules about, see e.g. https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7209/as-a-uk-citizen-can-i-just-turn-up-in-germany-with-my-colombian-wife-get-a-job?noredirect=1&lq=1 (even though they do not apply to British citizens anymore, the rules are still the same). https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/us-citizen-with-eu-spouse-who-doesnt-yet-have-a-job?noredirect=1&lq=1 might be useful too.

Comment: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/us-citizen-with-eu-spouse-who-doesnt-yet-have-a-job?noredirect=1&lq=1 was my case since my wife doesn't currently have a job.