# An EU Citizen wants to bring a non EU citizen with him to live in Germany

Tags: visa, family

I'm a British citizen married to a non EU, and I want to move to live and work in Germany, my question is what is the easiest why to bring my wife with me to Germany and how can I apply for a residence permit card for my wife
Thanks

Comment: @Gagravarr the rules for British citizens' spouses are very different from those for spouses of permanent residents.  This is not a duplicate.

Comment: We already have several questions on this topic. See http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/7209/as-a-uk-citizen-can-i-just-turn-up-in-germany-with-my-colombian-wife-get-a-job http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/5645/moving-to-frankfurt-with-my-swedish-wife-i-am-not-eu-citizen/5653 http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/2774/requirements-to-move-with-us-non-eu-spouse-over-to-germany-as-an-eu-citizen and http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6056/us-citizen-with-eu-spouse-who-doesnt-yet-have-a-job

Comment: Closing as duplicate. You might want to add more details (like from which country your spouse is) though

Answer (score 1):

You should apply for a "Residence card for family members of EU (except Germany) and EEA citizens."  See, for example, https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/324282/en/.

If your spouse is a "visa national," requiring a visa to enter the Schengen area, you will need to apply for a visa before entering Germany.  Under the relevant EU directive, this visa must be issued free of charge, but a cursory search of the web site of the German Consulate in New York did not locate the correct page with the details.  The EU rules are explained here: http://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/entry-exit/non-eu-family/index_en.htm